# How does baud rate affect power consumtion on a Xbee module?

Tags: xbee

How do baud rates affect power consumption on Xbee wireless modules?
For example: What would be more power efficent: Sending a packet with lower baud rate or with one, twice greater than the first, but thus saving time and being able to set the controller connected with the xbee module(and the Xbee itself) in sleep mode faster.

Answer (score 7):

Use the fastest bit-rate you can afford, so that the transmitter doesn't have to be switched on longer than necessary. Using lower bit-rates doesn't make any difference in power, but it will in energy, since it takes longer to transmit.

It also helps to use a single transmission to send for instance 100 kB than to switch the device 10 times on and off to send each time a block of 10 kB. That's because the transmitter has a non-negligible settling time, and if you transmit in 10 blocks it would dissipate power during 10 times this settling time, otherwise just once.